# setText without moving the text cursor

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm making an app where multiple people are able to edit the same document in realtime and I'm doing this via syncing a noSql database against the editext view in the the app, but I have a problem doing this as when I try to use setText to sync the database it moves the text cursor, so, is there anyway to not make this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Read cursor position
- Set new text
- set cursor position to what it was previously

Comment: That's one way, but it still interupts the cursor if the user is writing so I would rather find a way that dosen't move the cursor in the first place. Would using append still move the cursor?

Comment: If the user is writting then you should not sync not touch that. You need more logic, i.e. TextWatcher and sync on idle or lost focus